# using logged in user's info on all pages

Tags: php, authentication

i am using the following password code http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/password-protect.php

it is working fine but when i try to echo out the logged in user's info, i am only able to do it once, at the time of login. after that if i refresh the page, the page is still accessible but the logged in user's name is not echoed out
can someone help me with this
 i have the following code on the first line of the pages that i want to protect

```
<?php require("/home/abcd/abcd/password_protect.php"); ?>
```

i am echoing out the name by using

```
echo "Welcome $login";
```

Comment: save it in $_session, look in example http://www.evolt.org/node/60265

Comment: That script you downloaded is wrong in so very many ways. I suggest you start looking at other login mechanisms. Start with the ones that don't store the username and/or password (be it hashed, even if salted) in a cookie, then look at the ones that don't use GET to log out, be careful with the ones that output path information, forget about plaintext password storage, and don't let them clear POST variables so other scripts you don't use won't crash and burn. Oh, and especially don't trust scripts that loop through all your users to find out who is trying to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the script basically does is that it has a pre-initialised list of login and passwords stored in the array `$LOGIN_INFORMATION` .

```
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'zubrag' => 'root',
  'test' => 'testpass',
  'admin' => 'passwd'
);
```

Now it takes a login/password combination from the user and matches with the stored values.
As per your question , you want to show the name of the authenticated user.

For that you can use a session

At the start of the page(Very first line) write

```
`session_start();`
```

then
    `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` //the authenticated username

Now at the beginning of every page where you want to print the name ,write

```
session_start();
```

then

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

After you are done and you want to log out ( or cancel the session) write

```
session_unregister('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

That script stores the hash of the username and password to a cookie called `verify`:

```
setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), $timeout, '/');
```

As such you can't extract the `$login` directly, however you can iterate through the possibilities from `$LOGIN_INFORMATION` until you find it:

```
$login = null;
$found = false;
foreach($LOGIN_INFORMATION as $key=>$val) {
  $lp = (USE_USERNAME ? $key : '') .'%'.$val;
  if ($_COOKIE['verify'] == md5($lp)) {
    $found = true;
    $login = $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Benjie Gillam . Thanks for the response. do i have to change the existing script to the above or add something to the pages where i am including the password_protect file

Comment: Just adding the above code to your pages should work, but you could do it more simply by editing the script, just add `$login = $key;` after `$found=true;` in the original `password_protect.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

at the start of each page:

```
session_start();
```

when user authenticaed succesfully:

```
$_SESSION['keyname'] = 'value';
```

wherever you need to access it:

```
echo $_SESSION['keyname']
```